# WordPress on localhost can not be reached

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp

I am using wamp to host a local version of my WordPress site. It was working gine until I restarted my computer and now I get this error.

```
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
```

I tried restarting the services, and creating a new copy of this site under I different folder and the error still persists. My other non WordPress sites work  fine.

Not sure what is going on so any suggestions would be great.

Comment: check console log first

Comment: http://localhost/test/:1 GET http://localhost/test/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET This is what I get from the console.Also this Navigated to data:text/html,chromewebdata

Comment: It sounds like your web server didn't start on boot. I don't know anything about windows, but make sure everything is running.

Comment: You say local copy of a WP site, so you have moved the site... [See the WordPress documentation, moving a wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: I would also suggest creating a Virtual Host to run any WordPress site in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 0):

If you've moved your site to a different folder then the root has probably changed. Go to `Preferences` > `Web Server` and click on the folder next to `Document Root`, and navigate to the root directory that has your site then click on `Select`.

Also, make sure **Apache** and **MySQL** servers are running. Hope this helps.

Comment: I havent moved anything and it is the only wordpress install that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed your port number from default port number.

Open with the port number that apache server is listening.

In your browser give "localhost:portNumber/WordPress"

Example: localhost:80/wordpress or
          localhost:8080/wordpress or 
          localhost:8081/wordpress.

You Can check your port number from apache part config file.

Watch this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blmOFr8uZQI

Answer (score 0):

I think its plugin issue from the codebase. Just rename the plugins name one by one in **(wp-content/plugin/)** folder and check.